# war under target didn't include Spring and Hibernate config files

Tags: maven

I want to add my Spring and Hibernate configuration files inside the war file. Right now, it doesn't include config files at `"WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"` or `"WEB-INF/ConfigFiles"`. How can I include these files in my war?

[image]

Comment: I fear this is not your only problem. You should adhere to the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), that'll solve this problem and probably a few dozens more.

Comment: I want to deploy that war on AWS but logs showing applicationContext file is missing then I tried extracting and saw that there are no config files there after maven clean and install also...

Comment: I have put all the config files manually in target/final/WEB-INF and now it works for me .

Comment: Just so you know, that is not a viable solution for the long-term. The folder `target` will get deleted anyway pretty soon.

Comment: Yaa thanks for your reply but right now i need only war which contains those config files so that i'll deploy and test my application on AWS... Will convert my project structure accord to the Maven standards soon. Thanks for suggestion and help :) (y)